# Is "a pesar de del" a typo?

Tags: gramática

I came across the following phrase on [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arte_mexicano):

> A pesar de del apoyo del gobierno y los temas nacionalistas, los artistas nativos estaban un poco más a favor de los europeos.

I originally assumed that the "de del" was a typo, but I've found a fair number of other examples by Googling, so now I'm not sure.

Comment: Good  catch!  // I tried googling it too, but I'm not finding what you found.  If there's a name, for example a restaurant called "Del Toro," then yes, you could have a sentence containing "de Del Toro."  (E.g. Lo traje de Del Toro.)

Comment: Yes, that's a typo, it should have been "a pesar del apoyo". Note that @aparente001 makes a fairly good point about the reason why you can find the group "de del" in a sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good catch!

I tried googling it too, but I'm not finding what you found. If there's a name, for example a restaurant called "Del Toro," then yes, you could have a sentence containing "de Del Toro." (E.g. *Lo traje de Del Toro*.)

Answer (score 1):

Sí, debería decir "a pesar del apoyo". "Del" significa "de el", entonces "a pesar de del" sería una repetición innecesaria.